# Unity Rigidbody Click to move

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, rigid-bodies

I'm wanting to have a script that when I click in my scene, my player will rotate and have a force added to it and will travel until it has reached the clicked point in my scene.

Right now I have it working using Vectors and having my player lerp from one point to another. But I want to amend it so I can use physics and get a better sense of my player moving. Like have him speed up to start moving and slowing down as he reaches my target loction

My script now looks like this

```
public GameObject isActive;
public float speed;
public Ray ray;
public Rigidbody rigidBody;



public Vector3 targetPoint;
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    targetPoint = transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{


}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
    {
        targetPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        ChangeRotationTarget ();
    }

    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (targetPoint - transform.position);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    rigidbody.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPoint, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}


void ChangeRotationTarget ()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    Plane playerPlane = new Plane (Vector3.up, transform.position);

    float hitdist = 0.0f;

    if (playerPlane.Raycast (ray, out hitdist))
    {

        targetPoint = ray.GetPoint (hitdist);
    }

}
```

However, when I run this, he just slides from one point to another. Regardless of the drag or mass I put in my rigidbody.

Can someone help me make my changes? Or point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I didn't had time to test this, but it should almost be what you are looking for. Just apply your Quaternion and Rotation codes to it.

```
void FixedUpdate() {

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        targetPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        if (rigidBody.position != targetPoint)
        {
            reachedTargetPoint = false;
            if (reachedTargetPoint == false)
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(speed);
            }
        }

        //zoneBeforeReachingTP should be how much units before reaching targetPoint you want to start to decrease your rigidbody velocity
        if (rigidBody.position == (targetPoint - zoneBeforeReachingTP))
        {
            //speedReductionRate should be how much of speed you want to take off your rigidBody at the FixedUpdate time rate
            rigidBody.velocity = speedReductionRate;
        }
            if(rigidBody.position == targetPoint)
            {
                rigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                reachedTargetPoint = true;
            }
            ChangeRotationTarget();
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Interesting, but the code seems a little broken.. if (reachedTargetPoint == false) {} will always be false, since you set it on the line above. But I'm trying to figure out how to use the logic :)

Comment: Yeah! Sorry for the mistake! I really didn't had time to test this out, but you're right!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you modify the `rigidbody.position`, and your logic overrides the physics. What you have to do instead is to `ApplyForce` every physics frame, probably with `ForceMode.Force` or `ForceMode.Acceleration`.